# Tensorflow evaluate: Aborted (core dumped)

Tags: python, tensorflow

tl;dr: I input a word to my model, and am supposed to get a list of similar words and their associated measures of similarity back. I get an error: Aborted (core dumped).

My goal is to determine which words are similar to an input word, based on their feature vectors. I have model already trained. I load it and call two functions:

```
def main(argv=None):
    model = NVDM(args)
    sess_saver = tf.train.Saver()
    sess = tf.Session()
    init = tf.initialize_all_variables()
    sess.run(init)
    loaded = load_for_similar(sess, sess_saver) #my function
    wm = word_match(sess, loaded[0], loaded[1], "bottle", loaded[2], loaded[3], topN=5)
```

My problem is that I can't print out the words which are similar and the associated similarity measure. I tried (in main):

```
 sess.run(wm)
 wm[0].eval(session=sess)
 print(wm)
```

All of which gave me the error:

```
F tensorflow/core/kernels/strided_slice_op.cc:316] Check failed: tmp.CopyFrom(input.Slice(begin[0], end[0]), final_shape) 
Aborted (core dumped)
```

This tells me I'm not running the session properly. What am I doing wrong?

---

Details on the functions, just in case:

The function 'load_for_similar' restores the weights and bias of the decoder in my model (a variational autoencoder), and normalizes them. It also reverses the order of the keys and values in my vocabulary dictionary for later use:

```
def load_for_similar(sess, saver_obj):
    saver_obj.restore(sess, "./CA_checkpoints/saved_model.ckpt")
    vocab_file = '/path/to/vocab.pkl'
    t1 = loader_object(vocab_file)
    v1 = t1.get_vocab()
    v1_rev = {k:v for v, k in v1.iteritems()}
    decoder_mat = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.VARIABLES, scope='decoder')[0]
    decoder_bias = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.VARIABLES, scope='decoder')[1]
    return (find_norm(decoder_mat), find_norm(decoder_bias), v1, v1_rev)
```

To find similar words, I pass the normalized weight matrix and bias in to an new function, along with the feature vector of my word (vec):

```
def find_similar(sess, Weights, vec, bias):
    dists = tf.add(tf.reduce_sum(tf.mul(Weights, vec)), bias) 
    best = argsort(sess, dists, reverse=True)
    dist_sort = tf.nn.top_k(dists, k=dists.get_shape().as_list()[0], sorted=True).values 
    return dist_sort, best
```

Finally, I want to match the words that are closest to my supplied word, "bottle":

```
def word_match(sess, norm_mat , norm_bias, word_ , vocab, vocab_inverse , topN = 10):
    idx = vocab[word_]
    similarity_meas , indexes = find_similar(sess, norm_mat , norm_mat[idx], norm_bias)
    words = tf.gather(vocab_inverse.keys(), indexes[:topN])
    return (words, similarity_meas[:topN])
```

EDIT: in response to mrry's comment, here is the model (I hope this is what you wanted?). This code depends on utils.py, a separate utilities file. I will include that as well. Please note that this code is heavily based on [Yishu Miao's](https://github.com/ysmiao/nvdm) and [Sarath Nair's](https://github.com/s4sarath/Deep-Learning-Projects/tree/master/variational_text_inference).

```
class NVDM(object):
    """ Neural Variational Document Model -- BOW VAE.
    """
    def __init__(self,
             vocab_size=15000, #was 2000
             n_hidden=500,
             n_topic=50,
             n_sample=1,
             learning_rate=1e-5,
             batch_size=100, #was 64
             non_linearity=tf.nn.tanh):
    self.vocab_size = vocab_size
    self.n_hidden = n_hidden
    self.n_topic = n_topic
    self.n_sample = n_sample
    self.non_linearity = non_linearity
    self.learning_rate = learning_rate/batch_size #CA
    self.batch_size = batch_size

    self.x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, vocab_size], name='input')
    self.mask = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None], name='mask')  # mask paddings

    # encoder
    with tf.variable_scope('encoder'):
      self.enc_vec = utils.mlp(self.x, [self.n_hidden, self.n_hidden])
      self.mean = utils.linear(self.enc_vec, self.n_topic, scope='mean')
      self.logsigm = utils.linear(self.enc_vec,
                                 self.n_topic,
                                 bias_start_zero=True,
                                 matrix_start_zero=False,
                                 scope='logsigm')
      self.kld = -0.5 * tf.reduce_sum(1 - tf.square(self.mean) + 2 * self.logsigm - tf.exp(2 * self.logsigm), 1)
      self.kld = self.mask*self.kld  # mask paddings

    with tf.variable_scope('decoder'):
      if self.n_sample ==1:  # single sample
        p1 = tf.cast(tf.reduce_sum(self.mask), tf.int32) #needed for random normal generation
        eps = tf.random_normal((p1, self.n_topic), 0, 1)
        doc_vec = tf.mul(tf.exp(self.logsigm), eps) + self.mean
        logits = tf.nn.log_softmax(utils.linear(doc_vec, self.vocab_size, scope='projection'))
        self.recons_loss = -tf.reduce_sum(tf.mul(logits, self.x), 1)
      # multiple samples
      else:
        eps = tf.random_normal((self.n_sample*batch_size, self.n_topic), 0, 1)
        eps_list = tf.split(0, self.n_sample, eps)
        recons_loss_list = []
        for i in xrange(self.n_sample):
          if i > 0: tf.get_variable_scope().reuse_variables()
          curr_eps = eps_list[i]
          doc_vec = tf.mul(tf.exp(self.logsigm), curr_eps) + self.mean
          logits = tf.nn.log_softmax(utils.linear(doc_vec, self.vocab_size, scope='projection'))
          recons_loss_list.append(-tf.reduce_sum(tf.mul(logits, self.x), 1))

        self.recons_loss = tf.add_n(recons_loss_list) / self.n_sample

    self.objective = self.recons_loss + self.kld

    optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=self.learning_rate)
    fullvars = tf.trainable_variables()

    enc_vars = utils.variable_parser(fullvars, 'encoder')
    dec_vars = utils.variable_parser(fullvars, 'decoder')

    enc_grads = tf.gradients(self.objective, enc_vars)
    dec_grads = tf.gradients(self.objective, dec_vars)

    self.optim_enc = optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(enc_grads, enc_vars))
    self.optim_dec = optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(dec_grads, dec_vars))


def minibatch_bow(it1, Instance1, n_samples, batch_size, used_ints = set()):
    available = set(np.arange(n_samples)) - used_ints #
    if len(available) < batch_size:
            indices = np.array(list(available))
    else:
            indices = np.random.choice(tuple(available), batch_size, replace=False)
    used = used_ints
    mb = itemgetter(*indices)(it1)
    batch_xs = Instance1._bag_of_words(mb, vocab_size=15000)
    batch_flattened = np.ravel(batch_xs)
    index_positions = np.where(batch_flattened > 0)[0]
    return (batch_xs, index_positions, set(indices)) #batch_xs[0] is the bag of words; batch_xs[1] is the 0/1 word used/not;

def train(sess, model, train_file, vocab_file, saver_obj, training_epochs, alternate_epochs, batch_size):
    Instance1 = testchunk_Nov23.testLoader(train_file, vocab_file)
    data_set = Instance1.get_batch(batch_size) #get all minibatches of size 100
    n_samples = Instance1.num_reviews()
    train_batches = list(data_set) #this is an itertools.chain object

    it1_train = list(itertools.chain(*train_batches)) #length is 732,356. This is all the reviews.atch_size

    if len(it1_train) % batch_size != 0:
            total_batch = int(len(it1_train)/batch_size) + 1
    else:
            total_batch = int(len(it1_train)/batch_size)

    trainfilesave = "train_ELBO_and_perplexity_Dec1.txt"

    #Training
    train_time = time.time()
    for epoch in range(training_epochs):
            for switch in xrange(0, 2):
                    if switch == 0:
                            optim = model.optim_dec
                            print_mode = 'updating decoder'
                    else:
                            optim = model.optim_enc
                            print_mode = 'updating encoder'
            with open(trainfilesave, 'w') as f:
                    for i in xrange(alternate_epochs):
                            loss_sum = 0.0
                            kld_sum = 0.0
                            word_count = 0
                            used_indices = set()
                            for idx_batch in range(total_batch): #train_batches:
                                    mb = minibatch_bow(it1_train, Instance1, n_samples, batch_size, used_ints=used_indices)
                                    print('minibatch', idx_batch)
                                    used_indices.update(mb[2])
                                    num_mb = np.ones(mb[0][0].shape[0])
                                    input_feed = {model.x.name: mb[0][0], model.mask: num_mb}
                                    _, (loss, kld) = sess.run((optim,[model.objective, model.kld]) , input_feed)
                                    loss_sum += np.sum(loss)
```

And the utils.py file:

```
def linear(inputs,
       output_size,
       no_bias=False,
       bias_start_zero=False,
       matrix_start_zero=False,
       scope=None):
  """Define a linear connection."""
  with tf.variable_scope(scope or 'Linear'):
    if matrix_start_zero:
      matrix_initializer = tf.constant_initializer(0)
    else:
      matrix_initializer = None
    if bias_start_zero:
       bias_initializer = tf.constant_initializer(0)
    else:
       bias_initializer = None
    input_size = inputs.get_shape()[1].value

    matrix = tf.get_variable('Matrix', [input_size, output_size],
                         initializer=matrix_initializer)
    bias_term = tf.get_variable('Bias', [output_size],
                            initializer=bias_initializer)
    output = tf.matmul(inputs, matrix)
    if not no_bias:
        output = output + bias_term
    return output

def mlp(inputs,
        mlp_hidden=[],
        mlp_nonlinearity=tf.nn.tanh,
        scope=None):
  """Define an MLP."""
  with tf.variable_scope(scope or 'Linear'):
    mlp_layer = len(mlp_hidden)
    res = inputs
    for l in xrange(mlp_layer):
      res = mlp_nonlinearity(linear(res, mlp_hidden[l], scope='l'+str(l)))
    return res
```

Comment: This appears to be a bug in one of the TensorFlow ops used in your model: it should never be possible to crash the process using the TensorFlow Python API. I've opened a GitHub [issue about this](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/6088), and we should hopefully have a fix soon. Could you possibly comment on the issue and provide more details of the `VAE()` function that builds your model?

Comment: Thanks @mrry, please let me know if the edits help. I also changed 'VAE()' to 'NVDM()' to match my actual model.

Comment: Could you try it with the latest RC version of TensorFlow? I believe this bug was fixed over a month ago.

Comment: Thanks @aselle. My original version of TensorFlow was 0.10.0. I created a virtualenv and tried with TensorFlow 0.12.0-rc0. I got a new problem (hey at least it's different!): in the original version, the decoder (that is,     tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.VARIABLES, scope='decoder') ) has length 6. However, in the new version, it has length 0. How can that be?