# Tensorflow print value of a tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have trained a model and saved it. I can load it, and I can access the variables I want, but I cannot print values that result from manipulating the variables. Here is a quick example:

```
def main(argv=None):
    model = VAE(args)
    sess_saver = tf.train.Saver()
    sess = tf.Session()
    init = tf.initialize_all_variables()
    sess.run(init)
    sess_saver.restore(sess, "model.ckpt")

    #Getting the tf.Variable I want
    d1 = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.VARIABLES scope='decoder')[0]

    #Manipulating the variable
    res1 = tf.mul(d1, 2)

    #Printing the result - THIS IS WHERE ERRORS HAPPEN

    print(res1) #Aborted
    sess.run(res1) #Aborted
    res1.eval(session=sess) #Aborted
```

The error I get is:

```
F tensorflow/core/kernels/strided_slice_op.cc:316] Check failed: tmp.CopyFrom(input.Slice(begin[0], end[0]), final_shape) 
Aborted (core dumped)
```

How can I print the actual values of my manipulation, which in this case should be the value of the Variable times 2?

Comment: As I commented on your [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/40963017/3574081), this seems to be a bug. We're looking into it, and will hopefully have a fix soon.

Comment: Could you try it with the latest RC version of TensorFlow? I believe this bug was fixed over a month ago.

Answer (score 0):

This question references a bug that was fixed at the end of 2016.  The answer:  Upgrade to any version of TensorFlow after that -- 1.1 or later should be safe.